# AWS CodePipeline Add Github Source from CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm working off of the Cloudformation stack from this tutorial:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/continuous-deployment-for-serverless-applications/

It creates a pipeline with a CodeCommit repository as a source. I'd like to switch this to a Github repository. Here's the code that is defining this resource:

```
 Pipeline:
        Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
        Properties:
            ArtifactStore: 
                Location: !Ref BuildArtifactsBucket
                Type: S3
            Name: !Sub ${ServiceName}_pipeline
            RoleArn: !GetAtt PipelineExecutionRole.Arn
            Stages:
                - Name: Source
                  Actions:
                    - Name: CodeCommitRepo
                      ActionTypeId:
                        Category: Source
                        Owner: AWS
                        Provider: CodeCommit
                        Version: 1
                      Configuration:
                        RepositoryName: !Sub '${ServiceName}_repo'
                        BranchName: master
                      OutputArtifacts:
                        - Name: SourceZip
                      RunOrder: 1
```

How is GitHub defined as a resource and how is the authentication handled for a private repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For github you need to replace provider with github for example

```
 Pipeline:
        Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
        Properties:
            ArtifactStore: 
                Location: !Ref BuildArtifactsBucket
                Type: S3
            Name: !Sub ${ServiceName}_pipeline
            RoleArn: !GetAtt PipelineExecutionRole.Arn
            Stages:
                - Name: Source
                  Actions:
                    - Name: GithubRepo
                      ActionTypeId:
                        Category: Source
                        Owner: ThirdParty
                        Provider: GitHub
                        Version: 1
                      Configuration:
                        "Owner": "MyGitHubAccountName",
                        "Repo": "MyGitHubRepositoryName",
                        "PollForSourceChanges": "false",
                        "Branch": "master",
                        "OAuthToken": "****"

                      OutputArtifacts:
                        - Name: SourceZip
                      RunOrder: 1
```

For more information click on

[code pipeline thirdparty source provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html#action-requirements)

Here, is how to get github personal token and insert it to your code pipeline

[github personal token intergration into code pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/GitHub-rotate-personal-token-CLI.html)